# Issue with complex data type in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have an input.txt looks like the following:

```
{"charId":1111,"encounters":[{"alias":"A","guid":192,"data1":0,"data2":0,"temporary":1},{"alias":"B","guid":952,"data1":0,"data2":0,"temporary":1}]}
{"charId":2222,"encounters":[{"alias":"C","guid":544,"data1":0,"data2":0,"temporary":1}]}
{"charId":3333,"encounters":[]}
```

My question is how can I get the output looks the following:

```
(1111, A, 192, 0, 0, 1)
(1111, B, 952, 0, 0, 1)
(2222, C, 544, 0, 0, 1)
(3333,  ,    ,  ,  ,  )
```

P.S. Here's my script, but it only outputs the first three lines.

```
raw_data = LOAD 'input.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]);

a = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE json#'charId' AS (charId:chararray), FLATTEN(json#'encounters') AS (encounters:map[]);

b = FOREACH a GENERATE charId, encounters#'alias' AS alias, encounters#'guid' AS guid, encounters#'data1' AS data1, encounters#'data2' AS data2, encounters#'temporary' AS temporary;
```

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, `Flatten` operator will always discard the empty maps, so it will not be included into your final output. One option could be you can solve this problem using the below approach. I will not say this is the best solution but atleast it will solve your problem.

**PigScript:**

```
raw_data = LOAD 'input.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]);
a = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE json#'charId' AS (charId:chararray), json#'encounters' AS (encounters:map[]);
b = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE json#'charId' AS (charId:chararray),flatten(json#'encounters') AS (encounters:map[]);
c = FILTER a By IsEmpty(encounters);
d = FOREACH c GENERATE charId,null AS alias,null AS guid,null AS data1,null AS data2,null AS temporary;
e = FOREACH b GENERATE charId, encounters#'alias' AS alias, encounters#'guid' AS guid, encounters#'data1' AS data1, encounters#'data2' AS data2, encounters#'temporary' AS temporary;
f = UNION e,d;
dump f;
```

**Output:**

```
(1111,A,192,0,0,1)
(1111,B,952,0,0,1)
(2222,C,544,0,0,1)
(3333,,,,,)
```